# Why we declare actionTypes as constants instead of using them as strings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been working with React, redux for sometimes and I used to declare redux action types as constants because I learned it is good practice

ex - `const REQUEST_USERS = 'REQUEST_USERS'`
Can someone explain the difference between declaring actionTypes as constants and using them as strings directly?

Comment: we declare then as constants, because, let's say, we don't have to rename them in 20 different places if would've chosen to write strings directly

Comment: Imagine you used the  string value `AB` in 20 files, after some time you thought to change the value of the string to `BA`, if it is declared only once and exported it, then you can change it only in a single file, but if it is used directly as string value then you have to go other all those 20 files and change them one by one.

Comment: Mostly to ease refactoring (i.e. when renaming the action) and to have your ide/linter/typechecker point out spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in modern Redux, the recommendation is that you don't do either. While it still works that way internally, action types become an implementation detail that you as a programmer are not touching any more.

I recommend you read up on [modern Redux with the official Redux Toolkit](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) and follow the [official "Redux Essentials" Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) for up-to-date best practices.

Answer (score 0):

this is just like introducing functions in your project. Why do you use functions? To reduce rewriting the code again and again.

Similarly if you want to re-use the action types, it's better to store it in a constant and use that constant. In such a way you are not prone to any typos etc, while using it in multiple places